# Argocd deploy successfully but can't get the service

Tags: docker, kubernetes, argocd

I am trying to use ArgoCD to deploy an image in Kubernetes.

This is my repo:https://github.com/Howard-Chang/argocd-example-apps/tree/master/whale
[image]
[image]
[image]
After ArgoCD deployed done, the service can't be open on web.

[image]
C:\Users\Howard>kubectl describe service whale
Name:              whale
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app.kubernetes.io/instance=whale
Annotations:       
Selector:          app=whale
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.104.41.34
IPs:               10.104.41.34
Port:                80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.9:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            
Image:https://hub.docker.com/r/hcwxd/kubernetes-demo/tags

Source code:https://github.com/HcwXd/docker-tutorial/tree/master/docker-demo-app

Docker file:

```
FROM node:10.15.3-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 3000
CMD node index.js
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you need to expose the service `minikube service whale --url`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but it seems not work :(  I have updated in the post.

Comment: What is the output of `Minikube service`?